# Allow forwarding only between VPN clients within the same subnet mask

Tags: iptables, vpn, wireguard

I am using Wireguard (interface wg0) for a VPN on a server, where all connected clients have IPv6 addresses assigned by the server (controlled by AllowedIPs).

Let's say we have three clients:

- Client A, with 7767:1::a
- Client B, with 7767:2::b
- Client C, with 7767:2::c

I want to configure the server (i.e. using something like iptables) to allow forwarding between client B and C (since they are on the same subnet, /32), and deny forwarding between client A and B/C (since they are on a different subnet, /32). And I don't want to have to worry about specifying the subnet explicitly, everytime a new subnet is used.

Something like this would work (untested):

```
prefix="7767"

ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

for ((i=0;i<65536;++i))
do
    subnet="$(printf "$prefix:%x" $i)"
    ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -s $subnet::/32 -d $subnet::/32 -j ACCEPT
done

ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j DROP
```

Is there some generic rule that can be used for this scenario? Or maybe another tool than iptables is better suited for this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591128/compare-bytes-of-saddr-and-daddr-in-nftables) could be applicable? Written for IPv4, and honestly I don't quite follow the answer, but I thought it could be helpful.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround, except it wouldn't be less complicated than the workaround I've already provided, because you still need to provide a list of each subnet "number".

Comment: I've spent a few days thinking about this, and the only idea I came up with was writing a custom match module, did you ever come up with anything else?